# How to remove a Connection from the Debug Configuration options in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, remote-debugging

In Eclipse for your Debug Configurations, how can you delete or rename an existing connection? For example how can you delete 'RPi3 - RPI1' from the example below?

[image]

I've wasted almost 15 minutes trying to successfully do this and I submit - please help!

Comment: What happens if you press `Edit...` in that picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming these are IRemoteConnection connections, Open the Windows -> Show Views menu item and find the Connections view to open it. You should see the connections there and there is a Delete Connection menu item.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Doug, this works! For future viewers here is a quick step-by-step:

- Open the Connections View (Window->Show View->Other: Connections)
- Right-Click on the desired connection to remove and select 'Delete Connection'

[image]

That's it, sheesh! :)